# comboBox Text is not Visible in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

what i have tried is?

```
ComboBox ComboBox = new ComboBox();ComboBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
ComboBox.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(6);
ComboBox.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
ComboBox.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
string[] FontsList = { "Arial", "Arial Black", "Book Antiqua", "Calibri", };
foreach (string item in FontsList)
 {
    ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = new ComboBoxItem();
    comboBoxItem.Content = item;
     ComboBox.Items.Add(comboBoxItem);
}
ComboBox.Text = (string)((ComboBoxItem)ComboBox.Items.First()).Content;
Debug.WriteLine(ComboBox.Text);
```

when i tried to print it,it shows the text in comboBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the ComboBox to the panel to show it. For example, suppose you want to add it to a StackPanel named MyPanel in xaml.

**Update:**

You need to set the IsEditable property to true, the Text property will actually take effect and then by testing, you need to set the Text property in the Loaded event of ComboBox.

.cs:

```
{
    ComboBox ComboBox = new ComboBox(); ComboBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    ComboBox.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(6);
    ComboBox.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
    ComboBox.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
    string[] FontsList = { "Arial", "Arial Black", "Book Antiqua", "Calibri", };
    foreach (string item in FontsList)
    {
        ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = new ComboBoxItem();
        comboBoxItem.Content = item;
        ComboBox.Items.Add(comboBoxItem);
    }

    ComboBox.IsEditable = true;
    ComboBox.Loaded += ComboBox_Loaded;
    MyPanel.Children.Add(ComboBox);
}
private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox box = sender as ComboBox;
    box.Text = (string)((ComboBoxItem)box.Items.First()).Content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have used combobox.selectedIndex=0 and now it works fine.

```
ComboBox ComboBox = new ComboBox();ComboBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
ComboBox.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(6);
ComboBox.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
ComboBox.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
string[] FontsList = { "Arial", "Arial Black", "Book Antiqua", "Calibri", };
foreach (string item in FontsList)
 {
    ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = new ComboBoxItem();
    comboBoxItem.Content = item;
     ComboBox.Items.Add(comboBoxItem);
}
ComboBox.SelectedIndex=0;
Debug.WriteLine(ComboBox.Text);
```